# Launcher development - Home button not going back to initial activity

Tags: android, launcher

I have an app that acts as a Launcher. This app has 3 activities:

- `SplashActivity`: shows a splash screen while loading, then launches `LauncherActivity` and finishes. This is the Activity marked as launcher in the manifest.

  ```
  startActivity(Intent(this, LauncherActivity::class.java))
  finish()

  <activity
      android:name=".SplashActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:screenOrientation="landscape"
      android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  ```
- `LauncherActivity`: main activity for Launcher. Has a menu button that launches `DashboardActivity`.

  ```
   startActivity(Intent(this@LauncherActivity, DashboardActivity::class.java))

  <activity
      android:name=".LauncherActivity"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
  ```
- `DashboardActivity`: shows a list of apps and launches them through their launch intent.

  ```
  private val DEFAULT_FLAGS_APP_LAUNCH = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
  startActivity(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName).apply {
      flags = DEFAULT_FLAGS_APP_LAUNCH
  })

  <activity
      android:label="@string/apps"
      android:theme="@style/TNA"
      android:name=".DashboardActivity"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
  ```

All activities are launched through `startActivity`, including the apps.

I want the standard Android Launcher behavior, that is: when entering an app through `DashboardActivity`, if I click home button, go to the main Launcher activity (`LauncherActivity`), and when clicking back, go to the dashboard (`DashboardActivity`).

The problem I have is that when clicking home, it goes back to `DashboardActivity`, not to `LauncherActivity`. If I finish `DashboardActivity`, then when clicking back on an app, it goes back to `LauncherActivity`.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Could you show a bit of code around your intent transitions and android manifest?  It's hard to say how you're manipulating the back stack otherwise.

Comment: @Submersed I've tried a lot of launching options and flags to no avail. I will update the question with code.

Comment: ok cool so you are the launcher screen, I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely back/task stack related. See [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) for more information about the task stack.

When you go from `LauncherActivity` to `DashboardActivity`, the dashboard is placed on to the task stack. When the `LauncherActivity` is requested again via the HOME button, the task stack is restored back to the last `Activity` which was in use after launching the `LauncherActivity`, which was `DashboardActivity`.

You have several different options to resolve this:

1. Don't use a separate `Activity` for the "dashboard". Consider a drawer or even a `Fragment` which shows the content and can be popped back to the main `LauncherActivity` when it is done calling `startActivity` to launch another app.
2. After your `DashboardActivity` calls `startActivity`, it should call `finish()` so it will get popped off the current task stack.
3. Usually launchers are setup to be launched in `singleInstance` mode, preventing multiple instances of the launcher `Activity` to run at the same time.  Note that you'll need to support `onNewIntent` in your `LauncherActivity`.
4. To prevent odd interactions with the task manager, consider setting `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` when launcher your `DashboardActivity`.

Comment: Already tried 2 and 3. 2. That will always go back to LauncherActivity, when any home or back is pressed; 3. Still same behavior. Will try the other proposed solutions and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to get back to this. 1 exhibits the same behavior since Android will remember which fragment was loaded. 4 solves nothing, I've tried all flags and combinations to no avail.